# How can firebase open dynamic links without us having to change our apple-app-site-association file?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

We have configured our app to open **universal links** by uploading an apple-app-site-association file to our [server](https://acuityscheduling.com/apple-app-site-association).

Recently we decided to start using **dynamic links from firebase**, and after setting everything up, it's all working fine, and we can now open dynamic links created in firebase.

What I don't understand is, **how on earth** (considering that we didn't change our AASA file at all) does our mobile app know how to open google's special dynamic links?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly because its on a different domain! You'll notice the Dynamic Link is on something.page.link. When you entered your team ID and bundle ID into the Firebase console, it created a new apple-app-site-association file on the page.link subdomain.